# WiFi link within building, a few meters in distance but through a couple of walls & floors. How?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

3 stories beneath us I have a small work room in the cellar where I would like to have internet access to look up things.

I cannot pull a cable from my flat down there as there is no direct conduit accessible to me.

A mobile connection neither is an option, there is no signal down there.

Powerline adapters unfortunately do not work because it's an apartment building.

I thought about establishing a WiFi link, however I tried using a Ubiquiti PowerBeam AC I could borrow for testing with no success at all - that thing is supposed to connect over 15km!?

Are there any specialised gear for indoor wireless bridging or is there a certain best-practice to overcome the walls and floors in between?

Comment: "specialised gear for indoor wireless bridging" is called homeplugs. Have you actually tried them?

Comment: Homeplug use electrical wires aka Powerline, which is not an option, unfortunately... (see above)

Comment: You haven't explained what the actual problem is. (See above)

Comment: Does your apartment building have a shared TV antenna system by any chance? You could use MoCA. Is there a phone line in there, either completely unused or with an unused line 2? You could use HomePNA, if you could get into the phone wiring panel to cross connect the dry lines.

Comment: Also, get a quote on having a Cat5e (or better) Ethernet line run. It's better to pay a couple hundred dollars to a telecom/datacom wiring contractor to get an Ethernet drop installed rather than spend the same amount on high power Wi-Fi gear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run fiber or ethernet outside the building?  Warning - copper cable is vulnerable to lightning.

Note that you need a PowerBeam on BOTH sides, in AirMax mode, with the SMALLEST bandwidth possible, set for your regulatory domain and indoor use, aligned to point directly at each other.  Place them to avoid as much structure, ovens, stoves, refrigerators as possible.

Avoid ALL microwaves.

If at all possible, get a direct LOS by putting one PowerBeam outside your window, and another pointed directly at it through clear air from outside the work room window (if any) - the building's probably in the fresnel zone, which is bad, but you might - or might not - get something workable.

If that doesn't work, then you're SOL.

No, there is no wireless bridging built for indoor use that I'm aware of - you're trying to do something that is fundamentally a problem with the technology within the constraints safety and national radio regulations (FCC regs in the United States) place on it.